# Pause setInterval() when on active tab?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, onblur

I have a slideshow that rotates through images every 15 seconds using setInterval. I use onfocus and onblur to stop setInterval() when the tab is inactive. This is what I am using:

```
var timerid;

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerid);
    window.onblur = null;
    window.onfocus = function(){startTimer();}
}
function startTimer() {
    timerid = setInterval(displayNextImg, 15000);
    window.onblur = function(){stopTimer();}
    window.onfocus = null;
}

window.onblur = function() { StopTimer(); }


function displayNextImg() {
    x = (x === img.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        document.getElementById("img").src = img[x];
}
```

What I am trying to add is to stop the setInterval() countdown when the user scrolls down the page and the sildeshow is out of the view of the user similar to when the tab is inactive. Should I get the position of the slideshow and compare it to the users' position? If so stop the set interval countdown and start again once it is in view?

I am not using jQuery by the way.

Thanks for any help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: `StopTimer();` !== `stopTimer();`, in your `onblur` event, the "S" in "StopTimer" should be lowercase.

Comment: @Xero thanks for that. I didn't notice.